# Change background color for container on website bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm responsible for a template website via orchard and have no access to CSS. Newby to all of this so forgive me if very simple.

The site has a number of containers fixed by the template all of which the background is white.

How can I override the background color for just one container with limited access whilst leaving the others white?

I have options to use Javascript and HTML to override the CSS.

Comment: Do you have the option to modify the HTML directly or will you have to inject new HTML with JavaScript?

Comment: You can embed CSS directly into the HTML by putting it between `<style></style>` tags.

Comment: Mitch can you post some of the HTML?  And identify which container you want to modify?  A few options are available

Comment: You can add a style tag to that element `<div style="background-color:white;" class="container"></div>`

Comment: I've tried <style> and <div style> that doesn't work.  This code is added automatically <div class="fsi-main-wrapper">

            <div id="layout-before-main" class="group fsi-before-main fsi-before-main-home ">
            <div id="layout-before-main-inner" class="fsi-layout-before-main-inner fsi-layout-before-main-inner-home">
                <div class="zone zone-before-main">

Comment: Thanks I've tried <style> and <div style> that doesn't work. Some code is automatically  inputed such as the container which stops be accessing this.                             <div class="fsi-main-wrapper">

            <div id="layout-before-main" class="group fsi-before-main fsi-before-main-home ">
            <div id="layout-before-main-inner" class="fsi-layout-before-main-inner fsi-layout-before-main-inner-home">
                <div class="zone zone-before-main">
 This is what is added automatically but I cannot edit this and want to overide t

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways for adding styles to your tags:

**1-inline style**

This means you insert styles on each tag you want. for example:

```html
<h1 style="color:blue;">This is a Blue Heading</h1>
```

**2-Javascript**

You can use javascript selectors and change style of each tag you want. For example:

```js
document.getElementById("test").style.color = "red";
```

```html
<h1 id="test">This is a Blue Heading</h1>
```

**3-internal style**

You can insert `<style></style>` tag in your `head` and define your rules there.

---

For this case you said, you must use second option. Use **important** for your styles too.

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".zone");
x[0].setAttribute('style', 'background-color: red !important');
```

```html
<div class="fsi-main-wrapper">
  
  it is a test

  <div id="layout-before-main" class="group fsi-before-main fsi-before-main-home ">
    
    it is another test
  
    <div id="layout-before-main-inner" class="fsi-layout-before-main-inner fsi-layout-before-main-inner-home">
    
      and also this is a test
    
      <div class="zone zone-before-main">

        something here ...

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, just one more question how do I then make the background transparent?

Comment: You mean `opacity` in css?? @MitchBuchanan https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_opacity_box2

Comment: The internal style did the trick to make the background red, should have worded the original question better. The background I would like transparent or opacity 0. Would have to be internal style as above. Thanks

Comment: Your welcome. So your problem solved?? @MitchBuchanan

Comment: Unfortunately not, it only fades the color, so when opacity set at 0 it would have white background again. I would like to remove the background color or make transparent so I can see image below the container.

Comment: https://codepen.io/MitchEng/pen/QraZPm  I've only added what I can edit, I know to change the end number for opacity

Comment: Behind this `div` and `link` there is an image and you want just that image be visible and you want to remove that purchase button. is it true? @MitchBuchanan

Comment: I would like to be able to see the image that is in the container, currently that container hides some of the the website background  image. Other than the image contained in the container I don't want to see the white background. The container also has a number of other images

Comment: Thanks for your help I've managed to do what was needed just needed to add the javascript to another zone. Thanks